# Checking whether a String is a valid number: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception

I read a code from a book and it says that, in order to check whether a given string contains a valid number, and if so, convert it to binary (internal) form, the code should be written as follows:

```
public class Exercise5 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        String aNumber = args[0];
        double result;
        try {
            result = Double.parseDouble(aNumber);
            System.out.println("Number is " + result);
        } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number " + aNumber);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But as I copied the code and compiled it, it would result in having a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. What do you think the problem might be?

Comment: you should pass anumber when you run it

Comment: Where should the content of `args[0]` come from, if you do not provide program arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only array you are accessing is args. You are accessing the first element of that array without checking that it's not empty. This array contains the command line arguments passed to your Java application.

You should check the array before accessing it :

```
    String aNumber = null;
    if (args.length > 0)
        aNumber = args[0];
```

And you should pass an argument to your program.

Answer (score 3):

you should pass a desired number as a string when you run java file.

ex

```
java Exercise5 123
                ↑
              args[0]
```

but if you run without passing a value then `args[0] doesn't exist` because no elements in the args[] array .it's `empty array` .so you got the `error` `java.lang.ArrayOutOfBoundException`

```
java Exercise5  
                ↑
              args[0]  //Exception
```

the target of this program is check a String is number or not ..

so if you run your program passing a String which u want to check a number or not then you will the get output .how to use this program

```
java Exercise5 5
```

output>> `Number is 5.0`

```
java Exercise5 a
```

output>> `Invalid number a`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to Work Fine , I just Compiled and ran it , while running did you give the number as a command line argument? , it works just fine

run it from your terminal like this

```
 java Exercise5 56
```

you get

```
 Number is 56.0
```

In case you didnt know the arguments you give while running the program are called Command Line arguments , Example if you say 
java myprogname 5 6 7

In main your

```
args[0]=5,
args[1]=6 ...
```